# How can I send service commands from my Nexus 7?

Tags: nexus-7, 3g, ussd

I have a Nexus 7 3G and I often need to send network service commands (e.g., to use top-up codes or to activate/de-activate data-plans), but can't find a way to do it from the tablet. Instead I'm forced to take the SIM card out of the Nexus and put it into a mobile phone temporarily. Is there a way to do this directly from the Nexus 7?

Comment: Could you please clarify a little how you do that in a phone then? This might give us (at least me) a clue what exactly you are missing/needing. Are you talking about USSD codes? In this case, you might try to install some dialer app from the playstore (just a raw guess).

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. Some carriers allow you to send 'service commands' to change some options in your subscription. With my current carrier, if I dial something like *139# on my cellphone, I can check my balance, while *100# allows me to perform other operations (incl. top-up).

Answer (score 2):

I think [USSD Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iba.ussdchecker&hl=en) is the app that you are looking for.

It allows you to send USSD codes to your network without the use of a dialer. I haven't tried it myself though so comment whether it works or not would help.

Comment: Thank you (can't vote up because of reputation). Strangely, none of these applications are compatible with my Nexus 7 3G...

Comment: It might be because the `Telephony` app is not installed by default. This is required to have SMS, Call functionality including sending USSD. You should try a custom ROM with telephony built-in and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not very helpful - I'd rather avoid having to resort to custom ROMs to get what is usually standard functionality.

Comment: Any terminal commands available that will check USSD response?

Answer (score 1):

came across this, check if it helps.
......

i'm in indonesia, i use nexus 7 lte 2013, 
first i do is unlocked n root it. then i install ussd dialer from play store... 
voila.. its worked.. 
last thing i do is install xposed framework n xposed sms module.. 
no problemo with pre-paid card...
heheheheh

Comment: This needs more explanation.  How do you operate it after installing these things?